# leaflet - need to draw range radius semi circles

Tags: javascript, leaflet

i need to draw a graph of semi circle on a leaflet map.

It should look like the following image:
[image: semi circle graph] 
How can i do it?
Thanks
Efrat

Comment: Do you expect the image to follow the map or stay fixed when the map is panned or zoomed ?

Comment: i don't want the semicircle to be an image. it should be drawn like a polyline, and it needs to be able to rotate as well.

Answer (score 6):

Have you seen [leaflet-semicircle](https://github.com/jieter/Leaflet-semicircle)? Not exactly what you need, but might give you enough clues to implement what you want.

Did a quick example ([demo here](http://jieter.github.io/Leaflet-semicircle/examples/range-rings.html)):

```
    function rangerings (latlng, options) {
        options = L.extend({
            count: 8,
            interval: 1000,
            direction: 0,
            spread: 120
        }, options);

        var layer = L.featureGroup();
        for (var i = 1; i <= options.count; i++) {
            L.semiCircle(latlng, {
                radius: i * options.interval,
                fill: false,
                color: '#000',
                weight: 1
            }).setDirection(options.direction, options.spread).addTo(layer);
        }
        return layer;
    }
```

[code on github](https://github.com/jieter/Leaflet-semicircle/blob/master/examples/range-rings.html)

Comment: thanks, that's what i needed to do. one more question, since the outer radius of the circles isn't equal through all the lines (since we are drawing it over and over each time we add another circle) is there a way to draw it only once - for the biggest circle and in all of the smaller circle we shall not draw the radius?

Comment: Yeah, noticed that too. It's due to the fact that Leaflet actually draws ellipses instead of circles to approach how a real circle looks on a spheroid, which makes the centers move a tiny bit.
Of course it's possible to only draw the arcs for the inner semicircles, but that would require some more customization to the Semicircle library.

Comment: can you help me with that? i am not sure where the radius lines are been drawn in the code...

Comment: thanks for your help, i have succeeded doing this change after adding code to the getPathString method in the semicircle class.

Comment: @EfratCohen nice, glad I could help.